# Angular - Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, angular-material

I'm trying to pop up a dialog on a angular component, but when I'm trying to entry the component the Chrome's console log displays the following error:

**Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for DialogPopUpComponent!**

[image]

Here's my code:

app.module.ts

```
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DialogPopUpComponent } from './dialog-pop-up/dialog-pop-up.component';
import {ErrorDialogComponent} from './dialog-pop-up/error-dialog.component';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, MatDialog, MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DialogPopUpComponent,
    ErrorDialogComponent
  ],
  providers: [{provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {hasBackdrop: false}}],
  entryComponents: [DialogPopUpComponent, ErrorDialogComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

dialog-pop-up-component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-pop-up',
  templateUrl: './dialog-pop-up.component.html', //empty html
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-pop-up.component.css']
})
export class DialogPopUpComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ErrorDialogComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { message: 'ERROR MSG!', buttonText: 'ACCEPT' }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed', result);
    });
  }

}
```

error-dialog.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'error-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'error-dialog.html', 
})
export class ErrorDialogComponent {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ErrorDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Any help?

Comment: So those are two dialogs ?

Comment: Yes, DialogPopUp just wraps the ErrorDialogComponent.@trichetriche

Comment: why your DialogComponent in `entryComponent` ? shouldn't it be only `ErrorDialogComponent` in entrycomponent array ?

Comment: I assume you only have ErrorDialogComponent as dialog component not DialogPopUpComponent